# Numbers on blackboard

Tags: combinatorics

> All numbers $1$ to $155$ are written on a blackboard, one time each. We randomly choose two numbers and delete them, by replacing one of them with their product plus their sum. We repeat the process until there is only one number left. What is the average value of this number?

I don't know how to approach it: For two numbers, $1$ and $2$, the only number is $1\cdot 2+1+2=5$
For three numbers, $1, 2$ and $3$, we can opt to replace $1$ and $2$ with $5$ and then $3$ and $5$ with $23$, or
$1$ and $3$ with $7$ and then $2$, $7$ with $23$ or
$2$, $3$ with $11$ and $1$, $11$ with $23$ 
so we see that no matter which two numbers we choose, the average number remains the same. Does this lead us anywhere?

Comment: You  have started the problem the right way, by looking at small similar questions. Perhaps  if you work out the next case,  keeping track of the way  you got to each number (so write the $5$ as $1\times 2 + 1 + 2$) , a pattern and a reason will emerge.

Comment: Note that the resulting number has 636 digits, so it's not easy to compute even if you understand the trick and can do it 'quickly' (unless you use a computer).

Comment: Denote the process of replacing two numbers $a,b$ by another one by $a*b \equiv ab+a+b$. Show that $(a*b)*c = a*(b*c)$ and $a*b = b*a$ (i.e. the binary operation $*$ is both associative and commutative). This would prove that order is not important.

Comment: The same question has previously been asked on the Puzzling StackExchange: [Ten numbers on a blackboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/7862/ten-numbers-on-a-blackboard).

Comment: @MeesdeVries [with a computer:](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=156!-1) 747106292628289444708380937293831544659502112248691679154935029028947927533099589206864815366798234329153235562080607562019236871366935959116501738803666174537810867225241796085310597754619259343815926673638047312709851500780194770609766399999999999999999999999999999999999999

Comment: The question is phrased rather oddly. It seems that the number is fixed; so how can it have an average value?

Comment: @TonyK: _A priori_, one might imagine that the end result would depend on the sequence of _random_ choices of which numbers to operate on when. The average is with respect to those random choices.

Answer (score 51):

Claim: if $a_1,...,a_n$ are the $n$ numbers on the board then after n steps we shall be left with $(1+a_1)...(1+a_n)-1$.

Proof: *induct on $n$*. Case $n=1$ is true, so assume the proposition holds for a fixed $n$ and any $a_1$,...$a_n$. Consider now $n+1$ numbers $a_1$,...,$a_{n+1}$. Suppose that at the first step we choose $a_1$ and $a_2$. We will be left with $ n$ numbers $b_1=a_1+a_2+a_1a_2$, $b_2=a_3$,...,$b_n=a_{n+1}$, so by the induction hypothesis at the end we will be left with $(b_1+1)...(b_n+1)-1=(a_1+1)...(a_{n+1}+1)-1$ as needed, because $b_1+1=a_1+a_2+a_1a_2+1=(a_1+1)(a_2+1)$

Where did I get the idea of the proof from? I guess from the n=2 case: for $a_1,a_2$ you are left with $a_1+a_2+a_1a_2=(1+a_1)(1+a_2)-1$ and I also noted this formula generalises for $n=3$

So in your case we will be left with $156!-1=1\times 2\times...\times 156 -1$

Comment: Superb, really smart proof $+1$!

Comment: A really good one, +1

Comment: Quite impressive! Just so that it doesn't mislead anyone, because the lowest number is $1$ shouldn't the result equal to: $$2\cdot 3\cdot  \dots \cdot 156-1=156!-1?$$ Of course this doesn't change anything.

Comment: Yes, sure @Zacky ;) the 1 was added by me just to respect the formula for the factorial

Answer (score 46):

Another way to think of Sorin's observation, without appealing to induction explicitly:

Suppose your original numbers (both the original 155 numbers and later results) are written in *white* chalk. Now above each *white* number write that number plus one, in *red* chalk. Write new red companions to each new white number, and erase the red numbers when their white partners go away.

When we erase $x$ and $y$ and write $x+y+xy$, the new red number is $x+y+xy+1=(x+1)(y+1)$, exactly the product of the two red companions we're erasing.

So we can reformulate the entire game as:

> Write in red the numbers from $2$ to $156$. Keep erasing two numbers and writing their product instead. At the end when you have *one* red number left, subtract one and write the result in white.

Since the order of factors is immaterial, the result must be $2\cdot 3\cdots 156-1$.

Comment: Great point! I guess this proof belongs to one of those cases in which induction hides a little how obvious the result is.

Comment: Nice. I hate it when I know something but can't put it into words.

Comment: @SorinTirc: Or, you can think of such proofs as falling into the category of induction proofs that use a loop invariant. Naturally, the loop invariant has one less quantifier than the property under induction, so it feels and looks cleaner. =)

Comment: It’s maybe worth also noting that Henning Makholm’s proof is setting up an *isomorphism* between ($\mathbb{R},•$) and ($\mathbb{R}, *$) where $a*b=a+b+ab$ and the isomorphism is given by $f(x)=x-1$